# Navigation drawer - how to I declare my links?

Tags: vue.js, routes, navigation, vuex, dropdown

I have set up a navigation drawer, with a dropdown menu, now I dont know how I declare/ write so that when I click on the names in my navigation, it will redirect me to the route I want it do redirect it to. How can I declare it?

This is my index.js in Store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Kontakt from '../views/Kontakt'
import Historia from '../views/Historia.vue'
import Solid from '../views/Solid'
import Semisolid from '../views/Semisolid'
import Archtop from '../views/Archtop'
import Thinarchtop from '../views/Thinarchtop'
import Kontrabas from '../views/Kontrabas'
import Nylon from '../views/Nylon'
import Steel from '../views/Steel'
import BanjoMandolin from '../views/BanjoMandolin'
import Bas from '../views/Bas'
import Akustiskbas from '../views/Akustiskbas'
import Ukulele from '../views/Ukulele'

Vue.use(VueRouter)



Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {

    navigation: [
      {
        component: Historia,
        title: "Historia",
        path: "/views/Historia"
      },
      {
        title: "Elgitarrer",
        open: false,
        children: [
          {
            component: Solid,
            title: "Solid guitars",
            open: false,
            path: "/Solid"
          },
          {
            title: "Semi solid guitars",
            open: false,
            path: Semisolid
          },
          {
            title: "Archtop guitars",
            open: false,
            path: Archtop
          },
          {
            title: "Thin archtop guitars",
            open: false,
            path: Thinarchtop
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Elbasar",
        open: false,
        children: [
          {
            title: "Kontrabas",
            open: false,
            path: Kontrabas
          },
          {
            title: "Bas",
            open: false,
            path: Bas
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Akustiskt",
        open: false,
        children: [
          {
            title: "Nylonsträngade",
            open: false,
            path: Nylon
          },
          {
            title: "Stålsträngade",
            open: false,
            path: Steel
          },
          {
            title: "Akustisk bas",
            open: false,
            path: Akustiskbas
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Övrigt",
        open: false,
        children: [
          {
            title: "Banjo/Mandolin",
            open: false,
            path: BanjoMandolin
          },
          {
            title: "Ukulele",
            open: false,
            path: Ukulele
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Kontakt",
        open: false,
        path: Kontakt
      },
    ],

  },
  getters: {
    navigation: state => {
      return state.navigation;
    }
  }
})
```

and this is my router-file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Startsida from '../views/Startsida.vue'
import Kontakt from '../views/Kontakt'
import Historia from '../views/Historia.vue'
import Solid from '../views/Solid'
import Semisolid from '../views/Semisolid'
import Archtop from '../views/Archtop'
import Thinarchtop from '../views/Thinarchtop'
import Kontrabas from '../views/Kontrabas'
import Nylon from '../views/Nylon'
import Steel from '../views/Steel'
import BanjoMandolin from '../views/BanjoMandolin'
import Bas from '../views/Bas'
import Akustiskbas from '../views/Akustiskbas'
import Ukulele from '../views/Ukulele'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Startsida',
      component: Startsida
    },
    {
      path: '/Kontakt',
      name: 'Kontakt',
      component: Kontakt
    },
    {
      path: '/Historia',
      name: 'Historia',
      component: Historia
    },
    {
      path: '/Solid',
      name: 'Solid guitars',
      component: Solid
    },
    {
      path: '/Semisolid',
      name: 'Semi solid guitars',
      component: Semisolid
    },
    {
      path: '/Archtop',
      name: 'Archtop guitars',
      component: Archtop
    },
    {
      path: '/Thinarchtop',
      name: 'Thin archtop guitars',
      component: Thinarchtop
    },
    {
      path: '/Kontrabas',
      name: 'Kontrabas',
      component: Kontrabas
    },
    {
      path: '/Bas',
      name: 'Bas',
      component: Bas
    },
    {
      path: '/Nylon',
      name: 'Nylonsträngade',
      component: Nylon
    },
    {
      path: '/Steel',
      name: 'Stålsträngade',
      component: Steel
    },
    {
      path: '/Akustiskbas',
      name: 'Akustisk bas',
      component: Akustiskbas
    },
    {
      path: '/BanjoMandolin',
      name: 'Banjo/Mandolin',
      component: BanjoMandolin
    },
    {
      path: '/Ukulele',
      name: 'Ukulele',
      component: Ukulele
    }
  ]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

HERE is how I try to set up my navigationbar and tried to figure out how I declare the routes (my routing is working btw, but i dont know how to declare them in links.) :

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <v-app-bar prominent flat app style="background-color: white;">
      <div class="wrap row">
        <div class="hamburger col-lg-2">
          <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        </div>

        <div class="headerImg col-lg-8">
          <router-link to="/">
            <img class="picture" :src="require('../img/eagle.jpg')" />
          </router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app temporary class="navigation">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="SidebarHeader text-center">
          <router-link to="/">
            <div id="img"></div>
          </router-link>
        </div>



        <div id="sidebar">
          <ul id="navigation">
            <li v-for="(item, index) in navigation" :key="'item'+index">
              <i
                v-if="item.children"
                class="fas"
                :class="{'fa-chevron-down':!item.open,
                    'fa-chevron-up':item.open}"
              ></i>
              <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open" :to="item.path">{{ item.title }}</div>
              <Dropdown v-if="item.children" :list="item" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";

export default {
  computed: {
    navigation() {
      return this.$store.getters.navigation;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false
    };
  },
  components: {
    Dropdown
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is dropdown-menu, which I have imported to the navigation-file. :

```
<template>

  <transition name="expand" @enter="enter" @after-enter="afterEnter" @leave="leave">
    <ul v-show="list.open" class="sub-items">
      <li class="sub-item" v-for="(item, index) in list.children" :key="'item'+index">
        <i
          v-if="item.children"
          class="fas"
          :class="{'fa-chevron-up':!item.open,
                    'fa-chevron-down':item.open}"
        ></i>
        <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open"><router-link :to="item.path">{{ item.title }}</router-link></div>

        <Dropdown class="children" v-if="item.children" :list="item" router-link :to="children.path"/>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Dropdown",
  props: ["list"],
  methods: {
    enter(el) {
      el.style.height = "auto";

      const height = getComputedStyle(el).height;

      el.style.height = 0;

      getComputedStyle(el);

      setTimeout(() => {
        el.style.height = height;
      });
    },
    afterEnter(el) {
      el.style.height = "auto";
    },
    leave(el) {
      el.style.height = getComputedStyle(el).height;

      getComputedStyle(el);

      setTimeout(() => {
        el.style.height = 0;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

i know I am using Vuex, and maybe its not the best way, but PLEASE help me to sort this mess out!
I wont get it to work, even how hard I try to.. :(

/ Lisa

Answer (score 0):

I looks to me like there could be an issue in your vuex file for example:

```
      {
        title: "Semi solid guitars",
        open: false,
        path: Semisolid
      },
```

The Semisolid is a reference to a component, but in the navigation component you use, you are using it as a url string.

Otherwise, a console log dump may help finding the issue.

Comment: Oh, i added a compontent to each and everyone of the objects in my array, in my store-file. And it worked!! yey!

But now I have problems with the other views  to show, the ones that hasnt children. in other words, Historia and Kontakt-view. How do I declare in navigation so that they also are redirect to other pages?

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you figured it out. Sometimes when you are stuck, all you need is a keyword. Oh.. and I can recommend Vue Dev Tools plug-in for Chrome for future debugging, if you don’t already have it :)

Comment: Thanks! 
Do you know how I can manage to get the other views to show? the ones that are not within a dropdown?

Comment: so this line does not show in the rendered HTML? <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open" :to="item.path">{{ item.title }}</div>

Comment: yes the lines shows up, and the dropdown is clickable and whenever I click on a link in the dropdown, it redirect me to that route, but not when I click on the 2 that has not got the dropdown..

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now.. it may be because you are missing the path property on the parent route: Elgitarrer for example, doers not have a path: "/Elgitarrer". Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: hm yeah.. but In this case its Historia and Kontakt , that I want to make work. They dont have children, its just a name I want to click on, and get redirected to their routes.

Comment: This is how my navigation look like  : https://imgur.com/6ChXjXx

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Historia seems fine to me, but Kontakt has an issue. the path property references the Kontakt component, rather than a url like: "/kontakt". That may cause the code to break. I can see that this is the case other places in the VueX store file.
On another note, you may also consider moving all navigational routes out of the VueX Store file and into your routes file. It is cleaner.

Comment: Hm.. im trying to find the issue that you speak of. That the Kontakt has an issue. In which file do you find that issue? It looks to me like these both are written the same way.

Comment: look here : https://imgur.com/ZGtHVZD

and here : https://imgur.com/Xz58t4U

Comment: I found the import was wrong in both the router-file and the store-file, so I changed them, but nothing really happend anyway.

Comment: Okay, judging from your image, your routes index file is correct, but the problem is in your Vuex store index file. In this file, the Kontakt object should have a property like this: path: "/kontakt" instead of path: "Kontakt".

Comment: But the path in VueX store file for Kontakt is "/Kontakt" ?

      {
        component: Kontakt,
        title: "Kontakt",
        path: "/Kontakt"
      },

Comment: Hmm.. according to the file contents you posted, it is not:       
{
        title: "Kontakt",
        open: false,
        path: Kontakt
      },
It shoud be: 
      {
        title: "Kontakt",
        open: false,
        path: "/Kontakt"
      },
This way, when the "/Kontakt" route is visited, the Kontakt component is rendered.

Comment: Yes I know, but that is how it looked like when I first posted this issue-thread, but then you helpted me after the first comment I changed it all and posted this message: 
-- 
"Oh, i added a compontent to each and everyone of the objects in my array, in my store-file. And it worked!! yey! But now I have problems with the other views to show, the ones that hasnt children. in other words, Historia and Kontakt-view. How do I declare in navigation so that they also are redirect to other pages?"


- so in other words, this is how it looks like now : https://imgur.com/dJEky6r

Comment: Im abit curious if this code doesnt render links that hasnt got children under them. ,amd dont react with the path.. since its only 2 links without children to them, and both of them 2 isnt working. Am I missing some code here? 

https://imgur.com/5wsq6MD

Comment: Ah, okay. In that case: when you click on one of the links that don't work, does the URL in the address bar of your browser change to that address? for example, domain.se/kontakt?

Comment: no it doesnt react at all. I got an arrow when I hover them, but when I click, nothing happens. And nothing changes in the URL either..

Comment: Okay this tells me that the issue is on this line: <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open" :to="item.path">{{ item.title }}</div> try changing it to this: <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open"><span :to="item.path">{{ item.title }}</span></div> Now the router link is bound to the <span> element instead of the <div>.

Comment: I tried to change it, still nothing happens :( The dropdown still works perfect tho.. But the "Historia" and "Kontakt" does not. And no change in the URL ..

Comment: Hmm... that's odd. In that case I would inspect the console for erorrs or warnings that may bring clues. In the Chrome browser, you can open the inspector by pressing the F12 key, or right-clicking and selecting inspect/undersøg. In the pane, select the "Console" tab and see what errors you get.

Comment: I gave up on this. So instead of me having these two inside the routing, i made 2 separate router-links outside thw whole thing. Its not the best, but It works. Thank you so much for your help, it means a great deal for me with all this issues that I have been struggling about!

Comment: No problem! Great to hear you found a solution. You can thank me by upvoting and marking as solved :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214237/discussion-between-jcmortensen-and-mcfadden).